# PostgreSQL query -- column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update a table using a temporary table.

```
  Schema   |         Name         |   Type   |  Owner   
------------+----------------------+----------+----------
 pg_temp_11 | tmp_x                | table    | postgres
 public     | entities             | table    | postgres
```

---

However I am getting this error:

```
UPDATE entities SET "Name" = "tmp_x.Name" FROM tmp_x WHERE "entities.Ent_ID" = "tmp_x.Ent_ID";
ERROR:  column "tmp_x.Name" does not exist -- the column Name exists
LINE 1: UPDATE entities SET "Name" = "tmp_x.Name" FROM tmp_x WHERE "...
```

What is the problem? The quotes around table columns?

Comment: incorrect syntax I think... `update e set e.name = x.name from entities e inner join tmp_x x ON e.Ent_ID = x.Ent_ID`

Comment: Stop using quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what is the option when using table columns like Ent_ID, and not ent_id

Comment: Quite simple: if you don't quote it, you can write it any way you want `ENT_ID` or `Ent_ID` or `ent_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, ok, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are surrounding multiple individual objects with double quotes. If you are using object delimiters (double quotes), they need to be on each item, not on the entire combination:

```
UPDATE entities SET "Name" = "tmp_x"."Name" FROM tmp_x WHERE "entities"."Ent_ID" = "tmp_x"."Ent_ID";
```